# How to implement a simple prioritized listener pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an event/listener manager that has this function:

```
  var addListener = function(event, listener) {
    myListeners[event].push(listener); //assume this code works
  }
```

But now I need to change it so that it looks like this:

```
  var addListener = function(event, listener, fireFirst) {
    if(fireFirst) {
      myListenersToFireFirst[event].push(listener);
    } else {
      myListenersToFireSecond[event].push(listener);
    }
  }
```

This is so that when the `fireEvent` function is called, it will fire the listeners in the `myListenersToFireFirst` array first, then the listeners in the second array.

So it will look something like this:

```
  var fireEvent = function(event) {
    var firstListeners = myListenersToFireFirst[event];
    //for each listener in firstListeners, call `apply` on it

    var secondListeners = myListenersToFireSecond[event];
    //for each listener in secondListeners, call `apply` on it
  }
```

Is this the best way to accomplish this in JavaScript? Is there a more elegant way of achieving this priority list of listener-event firing?

Comment: You could use `unshift()` to add elements to the beginning of the array... So, if the element is prioritized, use `unshift()`, otherwise use `push()`.

Comment: You could put objects like {priority:anumber, handler:afunction} in an array that you could sort at each insertion, so that you wouldn't have only 2 levels or priority. I never found a legit use for a 2 levels priority queue.

Comment: I am interested in the very same semantics and cannot figure out a nice way of doing this. The accepted answer is of no help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe its a better way then mine.. but that is a specific way, i mean you have to insert new handlers in the block. This is a more generic tool, however it seems to have application on your case.

i suggest this:

```
//makes a closured function that calls this function after the other
Function.prototype.prefix=function(o) {
    var that=this;
    return function(){
        that.apply(this,arguments);
        return o.apply(this,arguments);
    };
}
//prefix=reversed sufix
Function.prototype.sufix=function(o) {return o.prefix(this);}
```

with this code you can append/prepend functions to each other to form a kind of chain, its usefull to add another listener or to track a functions usage, or even do adapt code with minimal impact.

some usage

```
function audit() {console.log(arguments.callee.caller,arguments.callee.name,arguments);}
function a() {alert(arguments);}
a=audit.prefix(a);


//a user function
function f() {alert(arguments);}
f("test");//just do the alert as defined
 f=audit.prefix(a);
f("test");//now arguments will be on console too

//a builtin function
//this audit example only write to the console the arguments being passed to it
function audit() {console.log(arguments.callee,arguments);}
//auditing alert function (not too usefull, but shows it works even for
alert=audit.prefix(alert);//alert is now prefixed with audit

//an event handler
document.body.onclick=function() {alert("clicked");};
document.body.onclick=audit.prefix(document.body.onclick);
```