# JavaScript Call a function when user ends an event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I call a function when a user stops/ends an event like so:

I have a hover Event Listener like so:

```
elem.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
    alert("hovering");
},true);
```

And I want to call the following when the user stopped hovering:

```
alert("stopped hovering");
```

Is there any neat way of doing so, that does not require using a normal mouse move event?

Comment: check this sample of binding functions to eachother:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839146/how-to-implement-a-simple-prioritized-listener-pattern-in-javascript/10839304#10839304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in Javascript the `hover` state is called `mouseover`.

```
elem.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
    alert("hovering");
    var mouseOut = function(){
        alert('Mouse leaved');
        this.removeEventListener('mosueout',mouseOut);
    }
    this.addEventListener('mouseout',mouseOut);
},true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the mouseout event.

```
elem.addEventListener("mouseout", functionName);
```

http://help.dottoro.com/ljtqkajb.php

Comment: @MarkLinus Your point. It says javascript, and javascript events. How is this not javascript or javascript events?

Comment: @MarkLinus This is not jQuery this is native javascript. http://help.dottoro.com/ljtqkajb.php

Comment: You edited the answer. Sorry, my mistake. I was commenting when you did it